# SQL Query with multiple JOINs and Comparison

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to build a query that pulls in data from a few different tables (using JOINs) and I'm just having some issues.

Here is the SQL Query...

```
SELECT Import_Values.id, 
       Import_Values.base_vehicle_id, 
       Import_Values.part_type_id, 
       Import_Values.position, 
       Import_Values.part_id, 
       Import_Values.part_number, 
       Import_Values.brand_id, 
       Import_Values.brand_description, 
       Import_Values.series_id, 
       Import_Values.worldpac_category_id, 
       Import_Values.price, 
       Import_Values.list_price, 
       Import_Values.core, 
       Import_Values.available, 
       Import_Values.weight, 
       Import_Values.height, 
       Import_Values.length, 
       Import_Values.width, 
       Import_Values.selling_increment, 
       Import_Values.popularity, 
       Import_Values.qty, 
       Import_Values.description_line_two, 
       Import_Values.detailed_description, 
       Import_Values.image_url, 
       Import_Values.thumb_url, 
       Import_Values.note, 
       BaseVehicle.YearID, 
       BaseVehicle.MakeID, 
       BaseVehicle.ModelID, 
       Make.MakeName
FROM 
    Import_Values
        INNER JOIN BaseVehicle 
            ON Import_Values.base_vehicle_id=BaseVehicle.BaseVehicleID
```

After getting the MakeID from the table 'BaseVehicle', I'd like to grab the 'MakeName' which is assigned to the ID but is not in the same table. MakeName is within another table called 'Make' and the table structure is like so...

```
[MakeID]  [MakeName]
1         Suzuki
2         Porsche
```

I thought I'd just do another INNER JOIN like so...

```
INNER JOIN Make ON BaseVehicle.MakeID=Make.MakeID
```

That didn't work, so I'm hoping someone can help me.

Comment: What do you mean by that didn't work, what was the output

Comment: Thank you for correcting the formatting for me, Tom! :)

Comment: Gratzy -- Actually you made me open my eyes and rethink my logic (I guess I'm tired). I don't know what I was doing but it works now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution should work.

An INNER JOIN will not select any row unless the row from BOTH tables exists.

I believe your problem is that your IDs from the Make table and the BaseVehicle table don't match.

Try running a left join to see which rows are showing up null.